# Set a class attribute in pytest fixture

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fixtures

I'm making a test class for pytest, I want to set a class attribute `a` that will be used for several test methods. To do so, I used a fixture `set_a`, which is launched automatically `autouse=True`, and invoked only once for the class (`scope='class'`), because setting `a` is costly. Here is my code:

```
import pytest
import time


class Test:

    @pytest.fixture(scope='class', autouse=True)
    def set_a(self):
        print('Setting a...')
        time.sleep(5)
        self.a = 1

    def test_1(self):
        print('TEST 1')
        assert self.a == 1
```

But the test fails with the following error:

```
========================================================================= FAILURES ==========================================================================
________________________________________________________________________ Test.test_1 ________________________________________________________________________

self = <tests.test_file.Test object at 0x116d953a0>

    def test_1(self):
        print('TEST 1')
>       assert self.a == 1
E       AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'a'

tests/test_file.py:15: AttributeError
------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout setup -------------------------------------------------------------------
Setting a...
------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------------------------------------------
TEST 1
```

It looks like `a` wasn't set even if `set_a` was invoked, like if a new instance of the class was created when the test is executed.

It works well if I change the fixture scope to `function`, but I don't wan't to set `a` for each test.

Any idea what's the problem here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn’t set the scope since you are already in the class.

```py
class Test:
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def set_a(self):
        print("Setting a...")
        time.sleep(5)
        self.a = 1

    def test_1(self):
        print("TEST 1")
        assert self.a == 1
```

This is how you should use the `scope=class`, meaning it will work for any class in your module:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
def a(request):
    print("Setting a...")
    time.sleep(5)
    request.cls.a = 1


class Test:
    def test_1(self):
        print("TEST 1")
        assert self.a == 1
```

Comment: The default scope of fixtures is function. Therefore, when you write `@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)` this fixture will be function scoped, even inside a class. As in, as far as my understanding goes, this answer doesn't quite answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the value never changes another option is to define it outside of the test method --

```
import pytest
import time


class Test:
    a = 1

    def test_1(self):
        print('TEST 1')
        assert self.a == 1
```